# Cron job 'enterprise_refresh_index' in Magento EE 1.14 running status, don't change to success

Tags: magento, solr, cron

I'm worked with Magento EE 1.14 and when go backend:
System > Schedule > Timelime View has a cron job name 'enterprise_refresh_index' always running status.
Based on my search result, this job re-run indexes in system. Traced into exception.log:

```
exception 'Exception' with message '"400" Status: Bad Request' in /public_html/app/code/core/Enterprise/Search/Model/Client/Solr.php:249
 Stack trace:
#0 /public_html/app/code/core/Enterprise/Search/Model/Client/Solr.php(289): Enterprise_Search_Model_Client_Solr->_getResponse()
#1 /public_html/app/code/local/Apache/Solr/Service.php(621): Enterprise_Search_Model_Client_Solr->_sendRawPost('http://localhos...', '<add allowDups=...')
#2 /public_html/app/code/local/Apache/Solr/Service.php(677): Apache_Solr_Service->add('<add allowDups=...')
#3 /public_html/app/code/core/Enterprise/Search/Model/Adapter/Abstract.php(612): Apache_Solr_Service->addDocuments(Array)
#4 /public_html/app/code/core/Enterprise/Search/Model/Resource/Engine.php(218): Enterprise_Search_Model_Adapter_Abstract->addDocs(Array)
#5 /public_html/app/code/local/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php(807): Enterprise_Search_Model_Resource_Engine->saveEntityIndexes(1, Array)
#6 /public_html/app/code/local/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php(228): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->_saveProductIndexes(1, Array)
#7 /public_html/app/code/local/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php(116): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->_rebuildStoreIndex(1, Array)
#8 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Fulltext.php(84): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->rebuildIndex(NULL, Array)
#9 /public_html/app/code/core/Enterprise/CatalogSearch/Model/Index/Action/Fulltext/Refresh/Changelog.php(93): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext->rebuildIndex(NULL, Array)
#10 /public_html/app/code/core/Enterprise/Mview/Model/Client.php(123): Enterprise_CatalogSearch_Model_Index_Action_Fulltext_Refresh_Changelog->execute()
#11 /public_html/app/code/core/Enterprise/Index/Model/Observer.php(129): Enterprise_Mview_Model_Client->execute('enterprise_cata...')
#12 [internal function]: Enterprise_Index_Model_Observer->refreshIndex(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule))
#13 /public_html/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Schedule.php(163): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#14 /public_html/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Schedule.php(541): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule->runNow(false)
#15 /public_html/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Observer.php(72): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule->process()
#16 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1357): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer->dispatchAlways(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#17 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1336): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer), 'dispatchAlways', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#18 /public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('always', Array)
#19 /public_html/cron.php(78): Mage::dispatchEvent('always')
#20 {main}
```

And:

```
exception 'Exception' with message '"400" Status: Document [114264|1] missing required field: type_id' in /mnt/house/public_html/app/code/core/Enterprise/Search/Model/Client/Solr.php:249
Stack trace:
#0 /mnt/house/public_html/app/code/core/Enterprise/Search/Model/Client/Solr.php(289): Enterprise_Search_Model_Client_Solr->_getResponse()
#1 /mnt/house/public_html/app/code/local/Apache/Solr/Service.php(630): Enterprise_Search_Model_Client_Solr->_sendRawPost('http://localhos...', '<add allowDups=...')
#2 /mnt/house/public_html/app/code/local/Apache/Solr/Service.php(682): Apache_Solr_Service->add('<add allowDups=...')
#3 /mnt/house/public_html/app/code/core/Enterprise/Search/Model/Adapter/Abstract.php(593): Apache_Solr_Service->addDocuments(Array)
#4 /mnt/house/public_html/app/code/core/Enterprise/Search/Model/Resource/Engine.php(218): Enterprise_Search_Model_Adapter_Abstract->addDocs(Array)
#5 /mnt/house/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php(780): Enterprise_Search_Model_Resource_Engine->saveEntityIndexes(1, Array)
#6 /mnt/house/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php(220): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->_saveProductIndexes(1, Array)
#7 /mnt/house/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php(107): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->_rebuildStoreIndex(1, NULL)
#8 /mnt/house/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Fulltext.php(84): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->rebuildIndex(NULL, NULL)
#9 /mnt/house/public_html/app/code/core/Enterprise/CatalogSearch/Model/Index/Action/Fulltext/Refresh.php(152): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext->rebuildIndex()
#10 /mnt/house/public_html/beadaholique.wiserobot/app/code/core/Enterprise/Mview/Model/Client.php(123): Enterprise_CatalogSearch_Model_Index_Action_Fulltext_Refresh->execute()
#11 /mnt/house/public_html/app/code/core/Enterprise/CatalogSearch/Model/Observer.php(188): Enterprise_Mview_Model_Client->execute('enterprise_cata...')
#12 /mnt/house/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1357): Enterprise_CatalogSearch_Model_Observer->processShellFulltextReindexEvent(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#13 /mnt/house/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1336): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Enterprise_CatalogSearch_Model_Observer), 'processShellFul...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#14 /mnt/house/public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('catalogsearch_f...', Array)
#15 /mnt/house/public_html/shell/indexer.php(170): Mage::dispatchEvent('catalogsearch_f...')
#16 /mnt/house/public_html/shell/indexer.php(216): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#17 {main}
```

I also to check again schema.xml file on solr server, field 'type_id' already exists.

```
<fields>
 ....
 <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>
 <field name="unique" type="string" indexed="true" required="true"/>        
 <field name="type_id" type="string" indexed="true" required="true"/>       
 <field name="store_id" type="int" indexed="true" required="true"/>
 <field name="in_stock" type="boolean" indexed="true" required="true"/>
 <field name="visibility" type="int" indexed="true" required="true"/>
</fields>
```

Does anyone has any idea to help me fix this problem?

Comment: is your document passing the field type_id?

Comment: yes, the document return also has field 'type_id'
<doc>
...
<int name="store_id">1</int>
<date name="timestamp">2015-11-29T06:07:20.319Z</date>
<str name="type_id">videotype</str>
<str name="unique">52478|1</str>
<int name="visibility">4</int>
</doc>

Comment: What I meant here is If you add document to solr for indexing which does not have type_id in it...? Is this could be a possible at your end...? Can you check for sure case by not passing type_id in one of your document while indexing and check the error...